# rsyslog regex global modifier

Tags: regex, rsyslog

Many regex systems have the ability to set a global modifier to allow for multiple matches.

Here's [how it works](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) in Javascript and Perl.

```
/g
```

Python [is a little different](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/python_regex/)

> Python doesn’t have a global modifier like Perl’s /g option. To find
>   all matches to a pattern, use re.findall() rather than re.search().
>   The findall method returns a list of matches rather than a match
>   object. If the match contains captured subexpressions, findall will
>   return a list of tuples, the tuples being the captures.

And the [list goes on](http://php.net/preg_match_all)...

However, I can't seem to find anywhere in [the documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/property_replacer.html) how to set such a modifier for rsyslog. An [online testing utility](http://www.rsyslog.com/regex/) is available but it does mention the following:

> Rsyslog uses POSIX ERE (and optionally BRE) expressions. This checker
>   works with the php POSIX ERE functions. So in theory, there can be a
>   difference between what the engine included in rsyslog (clib) and this
>   web app does. However, in practice the results should be fairly the
>   same.

Since the tool uses the php POSIX ERE functions - and the `/g` [modifier doesn't work in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578671/unknown-modifier-g-in-when-using-preg-match-in-php) then I believe there would need to be something comparable in rsyslog to the php function [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Any tips?